# How to check the device type of a WiFi host?

Tags: wireless-networking, backtrack, kali-linux

If I see a Wifi network, how can check what's the type of the Wifi host - a router, a computer, a smartphone, a tablet? Is there something like a fingerprint, similar to User-Agent headers in browsers? Probably I can do that with BackTrack / Kali Linux, but I don't know which of the included tools to use. I am open to suggestions for any other tools.

Comment: What's a "WiFi Host" ? That's not common terminology. WiFi topology comes in two main flavors, ad-hoc and using access points.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong terminology. I mean the device, to which I would connect if I join the WiFi network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a general idea of the device if you look up the MAC address of the device.
Something like [this mac address looker-upper](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/) would tell you the device type of the device with a certain MAC address

Comment: Hm, not bad, but, for example, if I enter the mac address of my MacBookPro it only shows Apple Inc under vendor and does not state whether it's a laptop / iPhone / iPad. Still this is the closest I can get for know so thanks :)